# Rails active record query to get data in a specific order

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am creating an application where I have to show the tagged images first after that I have to show the normal images and after that I have to show the rejected Images, right now I am using 3 different queries and then collecting it inside an array, it looks like a wrong implementation, is there a query which will help me to achieve the functionality as mentioned below so that I can also use will paginate with it.

my current implementation is as follow.

```
images = [] 
images  << @campaign.pictures.where("is_pinned = ?", true)
images  << @campaign.pictures.where("is_pinned = ? AND is_rejected = ?", false, false)
images  << @campaign.pictures.where("is_rejected = ?", true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in one query/line, you currently have to do it via the SQL string:

```
images = @campaign.pictures.where("is_pinned = ? OR (is_pinned = ? AND is_rejected = ?) OR is_rejected = ?", true, false, false, true)
```

There will be another option [once the `or` method is introduced in Rails 5](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or).

Other than that, if you're not concerned about efficiency you could make it look slightly prettier with hash syntax:

```
images = []
images << @campaign.pictures.where(is_pinned: true)
images << @campaign.pictures.where(is_pinned: false, is_rejected: false)
images << @campaign.pictures.where(is_rejected: true)
```

Comment: I have tried the above query but it is not arranging the data in the correct order as I need

Answer (score 0):

Just order on ActiveRecord::Relation:

```
images = @campaign.pictures.order('is_pinned desc, is_rejected')
```

Now `images` is an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation and you can paginate on it.

The key is in the order clause.

**Note**: I assume you can't have records pinned and rejected at the same time, if not your initial solution can have duplicates.

Comment: I can do this but in this case I will get the pinned images first and after that I will get the rejected images, I need pinned images first after that I need the normal images and after that I need the rejected images

Comment: This doesn't work if you have a ```default_scope``` with an order defined on the model (fix using ```reorder``` instead of ```order```). Or, you have null values on that fields. Or, perhaps, you have no records with false in both fields (normal images?). But, I think this order give the same order of your original ```images``` array.